# paragraph word spacing

Tags: html

Hi I have been using HTML for a while but today I have notice something about tags in html. I know you all notice it at the start of learning HTML.

My question is that Why we can't give more then one space in html `<p>` tag or in `<h1>` tag?

I mean why is this:

```
<p>ba ba             ba ba</p>
```

The same as this:

```
<p>ba ba ba ba</p>
```

Both have this result:

```
ba ba ba ba
```

I know space does not matter in html but `<p> <h1>` are container of text so why they only give one space.

How can I achieve this instead?

```
ba ba             ba ba
```

Comment: it change test to code I want text

Comment: Hmmm.. Why? Maybe answer is in HTML specification. I don't know but I think this is more question for HTML render engine not strict HTML language

Comment: This is too broad: there are several alternative ways to achieve what you ask for, and the choice depends on what *exactly* you want and *why*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to 'trick' it (not really tricks at all).

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hwn7/)**

```
<p>Hello there whats<span></span> your name</p>
```

With style:

```
span{
    width:50px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Which looks like:

```
Hello there whats         your name
```

---

There is also another option, using `&nbsp;`

This means "non breaking space".

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hwn7/1/)**

HTML:

```
<p>Hello there whats&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;your name</p>
```

Which produces

```
Hello there whats         your name
```

---

A third option is to add a `margin`.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hwn7/2/)**

HTML:

```
<p>Hello there whats<span></span>your name</p>
```

CSS:

```
span{
    margin:0 50px;
}
```

end result:

```
Hello there whats          your name
```

---

The way I'd do it is using `white-space:`.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hwn7/3/)**

HTML:

```
<p>Hello there whats                your name</p>
```

CSS:

```
p{
    white-space:pre;
}
```

End result:

```
Hello there whats                your name
```

Comment: There are so many different ways of doing it, but I'll add that one too! Thanks @robertw

Comment: you have edited you answer a lot from other people answer but it okay you explained a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `&nbsp;` instead of just space e.g.:

```
<p>ba&nbsp;&nbsp;ba&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ba ba</p>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84zkS/)

You can also read this guide:

[Non-Breaking Space in HTML](http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/non-breaking-space.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You want `p { white-space: pre; }`

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/LPnFQ/)

CSS

```
p { white-space: pre; }
```

HTML

```
<p>test test            test</p>
```

---

Depending on context, you may want to use `<pre>`.

[Fiddle for pre](http://jsfiddle.net/LPnFQ/1/)

HTML

```
<pre>test test            test</pre>
```

[More information on pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)